# How to loop through an array inside of array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to loop through an array inside of an array, so that I can display either phone numbers or extension number. For example: If a user has both (phone number and extension number) then I should ONLY display phone number, but sometimes a user has only a extension number then I should display the extension number.

And here's my code:

```
  <table style="padding: 40px;margin-left: -10px;margin-top:-38px;display: inline-block;">
            <div style="margin-top:16px;margin-left:10px;">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll"/>
            </div>
            <div style="padding:20px;">
                @foreach($resultArray as $key => $value)

                    @foreach($value as $key2 => $value2)
                        @if(is_array($value2))
                            @foreach($value2 as $key3 => $value3)
                                <?php
                                   // echo var_dump($value3);

                                if (in_array($value3['phoneNumber'], $value3)) {
                                    if (strlen($value3['phoneNumber']) === 11) {
                                        $value3['phoneNumber'] = ltrim($value3['phoneNumber'], 1);
                                    }
                                }
                                else{
                                    $value3['phoneNumber'] = $value3['extension'];
                                }



                                ?>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <input class="input_checkbox" type="checkbox"
                                               id="{{$key3}}customer-name-checkbox" name="{{$key3}} "
                                               value="yes"><span style="padding-left:40px;"></span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>{{$value3['firstName']}}  {{$value3['lastName']}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$value3['phoneNumber']}}}</td>
                                    <td><input style="margin-left:60px;float: right;" type="email" class="styled-text  rounded" name="{{$key3}}" id="{{$key3}}customer-name-inputField" placeholder="" value=""/><br/><br/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </table>
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please? Thank you so much in advance!!

Comment: Never use error squelching: `@`. Especially, while you try to debug your code.

Comment: @vp_arth the @ is part of Blade (Laravel)

Comment: Ouch, 'm sorry. Ugly syntax :)

Comment: What exactly is your issue? As in, what are you seeing with your current code and what did you expect to see?

Comment: @TheManiac I have a phone # / extension column, so I'm suppose to display there either a phone number or extension number for each  user. For example: If a user has both (phone number and extension number) then I should ONLY display phone number, but sometimes a user has only a extension number then I should display the extension number

Comment: I understand what you are trying to accomplish, but I don't know what is actually going wrong. I'm not a php compiler nor a webserver -- what are you seeing and why is it wrong?

Comment: @TheManiac my problem is that someone of the users have a phone number and some don't, and my if/else statements are failing :(

Comment: In your original code you need to use `array_key_exists` or `isset` instead of `in_array($value3['phoneNumber'], $value3)`.

Comment: @Midas thank you!!

Comment: @HenryDev You're welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your requirements, I think you need something like this:

```
<?php
foreach ($resultArray['searchUserResults']['searchUserResult'] as $key => $data)
{
    if (isset($data['phoneNumber']))
        echo $data['phoneNumber'];

    else if (isset($data['extension']))
        echo $data['extension'];
}
?>
```

This will output either of the two, but only `phoneNumber` if both are present.

You do not need all the nested `foreach` loops to accomplish this. Instead you iterate over the sub-array only.